# Figma - can it be used with WPF and Visual Studio designers?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2022, figma

I just saw Figma in real project. Immediately my questions is - can Figma designs be somehow imported in Visual Studio to create WPF Windows/Pages for example? Anyone has actual experience using Figma alongside WPF project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figma is just UI design tool. It keeps the information about geometric types:
rectangles, brushes, text, effets

So there is no ability to recognize to which type of control you need convert concrete shape in Figma.

However there are few plugins which might be helpful for convert to the drawing, canvas with rectangles, brushes and etc.

You can find they via open Plugins menu, and type the keyword XAML:
[image]

[image]